# Determine the power set, $P(A)$ for $A=\{ x: x=0 \text{ or } x \in P(\{0\}) \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is my attempted solution for this question but, is there other cases that I should consider?

case 1: $x=0, A=\{0\}, P(A)=\{\emptyset,0\}$

case 2: 
$x\in P(\{0\}), A=\{\emptyset, \{0\}\}, P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{0\},\{\emptyset,\{0\}\}\}$

Comment: I think you are missing $x=0$ in your set, in addition to $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$ which you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $P(\{0\}) = \{\{0\}, \emptyset\}$, you have 
$$
A = \{ x: x=0 \text{ or } x \in P(\{0\}) \}
  = \{0\} \cup P(\{0\})
  = \{0, \{0\}, \emptyset\}
$$
and the power set is given by all subsets of this, so should have a grand total of 8 elements.